# Mapbox GL - how to check if a point is inside a rotated bounding box?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I use Mapbox GL to display a map, which can be rotated and zoomed.

I need to add markers, but for speed I only want to add markers that are within the bounding box of the current view, and redraw if the view changes.
(The bounding box is NOT axis-aligned, but can be a rotated rectangle!)

I can get the bounding box of the current view with `map.getBounds()`.
This returns 2 LngLat coordinates for the NE-corner and SW-corner.

How can I check if the LngLat coordinates of a marker are inside this box ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if point is within bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295825/determine-if-point-is-within-bounding-box)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that answer only works for an axis-aligned bounding box

Answer (score 1):

Install the dependency `@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon` then create a polygon based on the bounding box points.

```
import booleanPointInPolygon from '@turf/boolean-point-in-polygon';
const bounds = map.getBounds();
const boundsGeometry = polygon([
  [
    [bounds.getNorthWest().lng, bounds.getNorthWest().lat],
    [bounds.getNorthEast().lng, bounds.getNorthEast().lat],
    [bounds.getSouthEast().lng, bounds.getSouthEast().lat],
    [bounds.getSouthWest().lng, bounds.getSouthWest().lat],
    [bounds.getNorthWest().lng, bounds.getNorthWest().lat]
  ]
]);
booleanPointInPolygon(yourPoint, boundsGeometry);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe make a polygon from bounds and check relation by [turf.js](http://turf.js) with [inside function](http://turfjs.org/docs/#inside).

Comment: Your link for `inside` does not work. As of now, it seems `turfjs` does not have an `inside` function.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've made your box into a `polygon`, test your `point` using `booleanPointInPolygon`:

```
const inside = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(point, polygon);
```

**IMPORTANT**: For best performance be sure to set your polygon's [**`bbox`**](https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygon) property which [`booleanPointInPolygon`](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-boolean-point-in-polygon/index.ts) uses internally for quick elimination:

```
let polygon = turf.polygon(coordinates, properties);
if (polygon) {
    // booleanPointInPolygon quickly eliminates if point is not inside bbox
    polygon.bbox = turf.bbox(polygon);
}
```