# How to find if coordinates fall within tile bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a tile map like this .I would like to know the lat and long values (41.850033,-87.6500523) is located inside which tileBounds?

Am getting tile bounds values for every tile. but i dont know how to check if latitude is inside the range of particular tileBound value. how to find?

here is a working copy of my code

http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/55Nke/

```
 var div = ownerDocument.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = 
'<pre><strong>tile:\n['+tile.x+','+tile.y+']</strong>\
\nbounds:{\nsw:['+tileBounds.sw.lat+','+tileBounds.sw.lng+'],\
\nne:['+tileBounds.ne.lat+','+tileBounds.ne.lng+']\n}</pre>';
 div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
 div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
 div.style.fontSize = '10';
 div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
 div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
 div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
 if(lat === 41.850033 && lng === -87.6500523){ //if latitude and longitude value inside that tile bounds set color as red
 div.style.backgroundColor='red';
  }
 return div;
};
```

how to check here if my latitude and longitude lies inside tileBounds.sw and tileBounds.ne?

```
var setTileBackground = 
this.mapDataPoints.some(function(el){
 return (tileBounds.sw.lat  <= el.latitude <= tileBounds.ne.lat && tileBounds.sw.lng <= el.longitude <= tileBounds.ne.lng)
            })    // never returns true ...
```

I solved my problem with this check

```
var setTileBackground = this.mapDataPoints.some(function(el){
 return (el.latitude > tileBounds.sw.lat && el.latitude < tileBounds.ne.lat  && el.longitude > tileBounds.sw.lng && 
 el.longitude < tileBounds.ne.lng)
                    });
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18295825/863110) question can help.

Comment: this solves my problem .....   var setTileBackground = this.mapData.some(function(el){
                            return (el.latitude > tileBounds.sw.lat && el.latitude < tileBounds.ne.lat  && el.longitude > tileBounds.sw.lng && el.longitude < tileBounds.ne.lng)
                        });

Comment: You should post your solution as an actual Answer, not just part of the question.