# Filter SQLite table with current coordinates in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I have Xmarin form cross-platform app which has a table called Customers stored in SQLite db. This table has Lattitude and Longitude for each customer. I can get the current GPS. What I want is to filter nearest customers with current GPS.

```
    public class Customer
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public long Id { get; set; }        
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string MobileNo { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int CreditDays { get; set; }
        public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
    }

public Contact GetContactById(long id)
  {
     return _db.Table<Contact>().Where(c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

I want to filter Customer table with current Latitude and Longitude to find nearest customers within 100 meters.

Anyone has any sample code can use to filter SQLite with entity framework?

Comment: you can easliy create a bounding box around the users location and use that to filter.  This would be slightly less accurate but a lot simpler than doing a radius search

Comment: @Jason I didn't do this before. Do you have any code samples?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295825/determine-if-point-is-within-bounding-box

Comment: what I want is a way to filter SQLite data. I have a customer table with lat and lng for each customer. There may be over 10000 records in that table. I want to find the nearest customers to my current location.

Comment: I understand what you want.  I don’t understand where you’re stuck.  What about the link I provided do you not understand?

Comment: @Jason I'm using Xamarin.Essentials to get geocodinates. First I can't find a way to get the bounding box from the current location.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location

Comment: @Jason Thanks mate. I'll try that and will update you.

Comment: May I know did that work?

Comment: @Jason Sorry for the late reply. I used another method. I wrote a function to get the radius to find the nearest.

Comment: @Sid Super! You can post your findings as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.